# Clarification on the  quality of "suggested edits"

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

As I understand, a suggested edit is not your normal edit that a 2k+ member would do. As it says,

> suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple
>   issues in the post.

and that's why we can reject them as "too minor" in the first place, but what actually defines a good suggested edit?

When answering the questions myself, I will often edit the question even for minor things like removing a signature, or fixing a single grammar/formatting error. I do believe though, that if it was a suggested edit, I would reject it as "too minor", hence sometimes when reviewing I'm not really sure if I should approve a given edit or not.

Any suggestions, apart from using common sense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For me that decision often comes down to the question "What's left?".

If someone suggests an edit which has a couple of things fixed, or a tag introduced, but leaves a serious amount of other problems in place, I might reject the suggestion as "too minor". Or when I have the time, I go in and improve the post myself, unselecting the "helpful" checkbox.

As I've said more often: When suggesting edits, or editing a post, edit all you can. Not just that one little thing you noticed. So if your edit consists of a removal of "Thanks" but leaves no other issues in place, the edit might be minor, but is not too minor.

And sometimes there is the case where a tag is added which really adds nothing to the question itself. A meta-tag for example. Or where a "correction" is made while the original really had no problem to begin with. In such cases I might also say that the edit is "too minor", since it doesn't really fix anything and is of doubtful value.

Comment: +1 for "what's left", I haven't thought of it in this way, though if I see a field for further improvement, I always try to improve the edit.

Comment: Do you read "helpful" as helpful to the site, or to yourself? If the edit is not wrong and I improve it, I tend to leave the "helpful" checkbox checked.

Comment: @bfavaretto Helpful to the site. I don't often unselect it. But if an edit fixes one minor thing and I have to spend significantly more time than I estimate the other editor has to improve his edit, I will unselect it. Not because the edit was wrong, but because the editor does IMO not deserve the +2 rep for a lousy edit. But as I said, these are rare occurrences and I only apply that to the most severe cases.