# Need some clarification on a suggested edit

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2461497) earlier today.

I have been looking at it for some time before making my decision, and I realized that the code has not only been made “more readable”, it has been actually changed a bit. There has been a `(` removed from the while statement. I know it is a very minor thing to bring up to you guys but still, I would like some clarification and opinions from you. If you look at the question and think about it, the edit (removing a single opening parenthesis) is not likely to affect a possible answer, because it's not a “why won't this compile” type of question. Since I know it's not a harmful edit because the code still does what it's intended to do or present I am thinking of approving this suggested edit. On the other hand I am thinking it's kind of an invalid edit to remove a character from code.

What are your thoughts on this?

ps. I have seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145053/clarification-on-the-quality-of-suggested-edits) already

Comment: In my opinion that edit is too minor, it doesn't do anything besides formatting the code in a different (indentation) style (which shouldn't be done, in my opinion). On the other hand, the answer isn't that great either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely reject this as **too minor**.

The reason lies in the definition itself:
[image]

I think this defines it well.

The current edit just makes change in the format and readability. It can't be considered as "`made code mode readable`" as the original post was also readable and doesn't cause any confusion. Another change is the removal of a pair of braces, that wouldn't have made much change even if it was there.
The intention of the question is pretty clear from the original post itself. So, in my opinion the edit didn't help the question in any way.

Well, approving or rejecting suggested edits are one's personal choice .They might have found it useful.

Comment: thanks bud. I was going for rejection too - but someone has already approved it while I was reading it so I just had to skip that one

Comment: 2 downvotes in single day!! You guys are just awesome....no worries

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, whether an edit is "Too minor" or not is a very subjective issue.

I'd approve this suggested edit:

- The way the original code is written, it's readable but the indentation and spacing is sloppy, making it pretty ugly to look at. Admittedly the editor went a bit overboard with the formatting – for one, I think changing the brace style is unnecessary, and adding the space around operators is slightly unnecessary although it does make the code look less cramped.

  The end result though, is a better looking code. True, the code isn't *that* long so it isn't really *all that* significant.
- Removing the extraneous `(` changes the code from possibly non-compiling code to working code. So while it's not a big change, it is *something*. And correcting an obvious typo in **the code of an answer** is an acceptable edit.

With all the above in mind, I'd say the suggested edit is not too minor (neither is it invalid), at least in my books.

However, the editor should have taken care to mention about the extraneous `(` in the **edit comment** though, e.g.

> improved readability of the code (made the indentation consistent); removed the extra `(` which would have cause the code not to compile.